# GIMP - How copy/paste shape- in my case, a rectangle?

Tags: gimp

I know I can using the rectangle selector then using `edit=>stroke selection` to make my selection's shape a solid rectangle's shape. Now I would copy the exact same selection's rectangle to variate the same rectangle's shape with other stroke type.
Currently I have to redo a selection and approximate the original's shape, I can alo use the guides lines, that said there is still approximation and it demand a 
 questionning amount of time.

I am sure it exists other means to achieve a more programmatic shape's duplication.

thanks for any hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Move tool in "Move selection" mode (red square icon).

[image]

It will move the selection mask (and not a layer) so you can translate your selection. Don't forget to reset it to Layer mode afterwards, otherwise you will wonder why the Move tool has become non-functional.

If you want to keep a copy of the selection at a specific position, use *Select>Save to channel* to save the selection before moving it (and possibly use the Channels list to rename the save selection to something more meaningful).